# What is different between visual studio F5, ctrl+F5, or running outside of visual studio?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have written a program in vc++ that has different behavior in various case as below.

When I run it by F5 it works properly in release mode.

When I run it by ctrl + F5 it crashes when I start to send data to the program.

Outside of visual studio it crashes immediately.

I don't know how to find the bug. Any idea on
what is different between these cases?

Comment: The usual reason is an uninitialzed variable that gets different random values depending on how the program is started.

Comment: this depend to envirment var? how I can track the bug.

Comment: It could depend on the environment too. Or that it starts in different directories (if you use any files). Otherwise you might have something like `int i;`, where `i` is used before being assigned a value.

Answer (score 16):

Running ctrl + F5 will run the application without debugger.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8b59xk0f(v=vs.90).aspx)
This is not the same as running in release mode.

You can run your application in debug mode but without debugger.
It sounds stupid but is for example helpful if you want to stop the console from closing on exit. ([How to stop console from closing on exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118073/how-to-stop-console-from-closing-on-exit))

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand the difference between running an application in debug mode and release mode. F5 will generally help you to debug the application and ctrl + F5 will execute the application. There might be some issues in release mode that makes your vs to crash. Read [this](http://www.flounder.com/debug_release.htm) to get an understanding.

Comment: thanks but my quesion is all about release mode some time in release mode crushed (F5+ctrl) or out of VC and by F5 work peroperly.

Comment: @herzlshemuelian: you are trying to debug in release mode

Comment: beacuse this happend only in release mode(ctrl+F5 and not in F5) I have to do it.

Comment: @herzlshemuelian: This may be because of buffer overflow or uninitialized variables