# How can I make changes on my code in vs-community and not to restart my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core

How can I avoid restart my .net application for every change I make on my code? I know there is a way on which you just compile the application and then refresh the explorer and all the changes you made on code are there but I can't remember how is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the application use Ctrl F5.  [The differences between using F5 and Ctrl F5 are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202088/what-is-different-between-visual-studio-f5-ctrlf5-or-running-outside-of-visua).